# Подключение шрифтов к сайту

Tags: html, css, css3

Подключил шрифт на сайт с разными начертаниями, 2 начертания подключил немного иначе и результат отображения немного удивил.

Как подключал:

```
/*---1---*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Raleway Thin'), local('Raleway-Thin'),
    url("/font/Raleway-Thin.eot");
  src: local('Raleway Thin'), local('Raleway-Thin'),
    url("/font/Raleway-Thin.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/font/Raleway-Thin.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("/font/Raleway-Thin.svg") format("svg"),
    url("/font/Raleway-Thin.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/font/Raleway-Thin.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/font/Raleway-Thin.woff2") format("woff2");
}    
@font-face {
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Raleway'), url("/font/Raleway-Regular.eot");
  src: local('Raleway'), url("/font/Raleway-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
  /* все как в первом, имя файлов в соответствии с начертанием */ 
}
/*---2---*/
@font-face {
  font-family: "Raleway-ThinItalic";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("/font/Raleway-Thin-Italic.eot");
  src: url("/font/Raleway-Thin-Italic.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  /* все как в первом, имя файлов в соответствии с начертанием */
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Raleway-Italic";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("/font/Raleway-Regular-Italic.eot");
  src: url("/font/Raleway-Regular-Italic.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
  /* все как в первом, имя файлов в соответствии с начертанием */ 
}
```

Как использовал:

```
<span style='font-size: 18px; font-family: "Raleway";'>Raleway-Regular</span><br>
<span style='font-size: 18px; font-family: "Raleway-Italic";'>Raleway-Italic</span><br>
<span style='font-size: 18px; font-family: "Raleway"; font-weight:100;'>Raleway-Thin</span><br>
<span style='font-size: 18px; font-family: "Raleway-ThinItalic";'>Raleway-ThinItalic</span><br>
```

Результат стал неожиданным когда открыл файл через телефон (iOS 12.1.2) и вот в чем отличие:

[image: Открыто через телефон]

На ПК у всех 4х начертаний одинаковый размер.

Почему так могло произойти и у каких начертаний в итоге `размер 18px`?
И в чем разница между методами подключения?

---

Подключил с гугла, результат тот же

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway-ThinItalic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Raleway Thin Italic'), local('Raleway-ThinItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptqg8zYS_SKggPNyCgwLrFoJfU.woff2) format('woff2');
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway-Italic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Raleway Italic'), local('Raleway-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptsg8zYS_SKggPNyCg4TYFq.woff2) format('woff2');
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Raleway Thin'), local('Raleway-Thin'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptsg8zYS_SKggPNwE44TYFq.woff2) format('woff2');
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0ITw.woff2) format('woff2');
```

---

После добавления `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` все стало одним размером и судя по всему `18px` был у курсива.

Остался только вопрос о разнице подключения шрифтов

Comment: А если на ПК масштаб покрутить?

Comment: @andreymal все равно одинаково

Comment: Может шрифт с багами? Вот пример с google там всё в порядке - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway  Попробуйте с гугла подключить для теста.

Comment: @Alexander Semikashev там без кириллицы, но попробую сейчас, а шрифт с github брал

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev А нет, все тоже самое

Comment: Если не забыть прописать meta viewport, то размеры одинаковые. А с отображением размеров шрифтов на десктопных сайтах у мобильных браузеров всегда были проблемы

Comment: @andreymal вот его то я и не писал, теперь как надо. Тут уже любопытство осталось, почему так вышло судя по всему какие то отличия есть как подключить шрифт.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Подключение google fonts** происходит 2-мя способами:

   - В `head` через `link`

     ```
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,500,500i" rel="stylesheet">
     ```
   - Либо в style

     ```
      <style>
       @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300i,400,500,500i');
      </style>
     ```

   Использование:

   ```
        body { font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; }
        i { font-weight: 300; font-style:italic; }
        p { font-weight: 500; }
   ```

   Все это на сайте подробно описано: [fonts.google.com](https://fonts.google.com/?query=Ralew&selection.family=Raleway:300,400,500)
2. Если Вы добавляете шрифт, какого **нет в google fonts**, то рекомендую использовать генераторы шрифтов для веба.

   Например: [font2web](http://www.font2web.com/) и [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Загружаете шрифт в `.otf` или `.ttf` формате и на выходе получаете готовые стили, которые копируете и вставляете в своем css. Естественно проверяя пути к Вашим шрифтам.

   На выходе получается такой код:

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'Raleway-Thin';
     src: url('../fonts/Raleway-Thin/Raleway-Thin.eot');
     src: local('Raleway-Thin'),
       url('../fonts/Raleway-Thin/Raleway-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/Raleway-Thin/Raleway-Thin.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/Raleway-Thin/Raleway-Thin.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style: normal;
   }


   @font-face {
     font-family: 'Raleway-ThinItalic';
     src: url('../fonts/Raleway-ThinItalic/Raleway-ThinItalic.eot');
     src: local('Raleway-ThinItalic'),
       url('../fonts/Raleway-ThinItalic/Raleway-ThinItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/Raleway-ThinItalic/Raleway-ThinItalic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/Raleway-ThinItalic/Raleway-ThinItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
     font-weight: 300;
     font-style: italic;
   }
   ....
   ```

   Использование:

   ```
   body { font-family: 'Raleway-Thin'; font-weight: 300; font-style: normal; }
   i { font-family: 'Raleway-ThinItalic'; font-weight: 300; font-style: italic; }
   ```
3. **Шрифт Raleway есть только для латиницы** (английский текст, для русского не будет работать). Если Вы нашли где-нибудь Raleway Cyr, то вероятно это какой-то "самопальный" шрифт. И зачастую с такими шрифтами возникают проблемы при отображении. Возможно стоит поискать другой шрифт с поддержкой кириллицы.

Comment: Кириллицу на raleway брал тут https://github.com/impallari/Raleway/, а по разницам подключения имеется ввиду либо в font-family указывать название шрифта, а начертания в font-weight или же в font-family писать название шрифта с начертанием, а font-weight везде normal

Comment: @JarryRoxwell, скачиваете все шрифты ttf https://github.com/impallari/Raleway/tree/master/fonts/v3.000%20Fontlab/TTF или otf последней стабильной версии. Потом каждый этот шрифт загружаете в генератор (в ответе приведены примеры) и генерируете стили, которые потом вставляете в Ваши стили, шрифты размещаете в своих шрифтах и используете.